# Regular expression to exclude URLs from web crawler

Tags: regex, url, web-crawler, sitemap

I am using an online tool to crawl my client's website and provide a list of pages / URLs that exist on it.

There is an option to exclude pages, and it gives a regex example of `\?.*page=.*$`

I would like to ignore everything in the news section (*apart* from the News page itself)

So would I go with the following?

`\?.*news/.*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a regex that matches `news/foo` or `news/foo/bar`, but not `news/`.

You can use this regex for that: `.*news/.+`

`.*` string starts with 0 or more character(s)

`news/` string includes news/

`.+` string ends with 1 or more character(s)

http://regexr.com/3ffj1